# measure theory, sigma algebra, sigma field

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a general sample space $\Omega$. Consider a set $B\in \Sigma$.
Show that $F = \{A\cap B : A\in \Sigma\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $B$. Is it still true when $B$ is a subset of $\Omega$ that does not belong to $\Sigma$?

**My solution is:**

Say $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $A=\{\{1\}\}$ and $B=\{\{1\},\{2,3,4\}\}$

Clearly $A\cap B = \{1\}$

If $B\in \Sigma$. Then $\Sigma = \sigma(B) = \{\emptyset, \Omega,\{1\},\{2,3,4,5,6\},\{2,3,4\},\{1,5,6\},\{1,2,3,4\},\{5,6\}\}$

$F = \{A\cap B : A\in \Sigma\}$

$A\cap B = \{1\}$ which is in $\Sigma$

$A=\{1\}$ which is also in $\Sigma$

Therefore, $F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $B$.

Can anyone check my answer please? I not sure if I've done it in a correctly. Actually I got confused by the field $F$.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you're claiming the answer to the question is yes, you need to give a general proof that it works for all $\sigma$-algebras $F$ and all sets $B$ inside any set $\Omega$.  Your single example shows only that it *could* be true.